# Could not create a bot on Server 4.0.3

Tags: xcode, git, continuous-integration, xcode-bots, xcode-server

I try to create a Bot for mac Server 4.0.3 on OS X 10.10.2. I update checkout repository with existing SSH key, but always get the same error : "Bot creation failed with error: Internal Error Creating Bot".

Could anyone help how to resolve this issue or give any explanation why it happened?

Comment: In the OS Xserver, did you set ON(Green color) of xcode server in settings.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but I was not able to solve the root cause.
The only workaround I have found was to create the bot directly on the CI server.

The issue I think is due to something related to the certificates but I was not able to find out what.

HTH